# Twitter Integration Using Twitter4j

Tags: java, android, twitter

I Working on Android application.I am Making One Application and i need to Integrate Twitter in My Application.Login is Successfully Done but i need Email address of Login User.
I am used [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) library to integrate twitter in my application.I also tried [Fabric](http://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/index.html) for integrate Twitter but get Same Result.

But i need Login user's Email Address.

All above mention link working fine but no one can provide login user Email Address.

Is there any one have any idea for Solve this issue...?
Thanks,

Comment: What is the problem ? You can use your own email ID ? Please explain your problem clearly.

Comment: Twitter doesn't provide the user's email address via the API.

Comment: What is the process to get Email address in Twitter integration.??

Answer (score 0):

in Order to request "user's Email Address" your app need to be whitelisted by Twitter

> Requesting a User’s Email Address requires your application to be whitelisted by Twitter. To request access, please visit https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform.

[Link](http://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/request-user-email-address.html)

Please contact Twitter support service to know the process : support@crashlytics.com

they will ask you about why you need to collecte emails.

Hope this helps